# How to use "Welcome aboard" right

Tags: greetings

**Welcome aboard the xyz train.**

**Welcome aboard on the xyz train.**

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?

I don't really know how to use the "Welcome aboard" part right, greeting someone for their coming on board on whatever train/plane I'm on.

Like when they make inflight announcements saying "Welcome aboard xyz airlines".
Is it okay to use the preposition **on** following the aboard in constructions like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We never use **on** or any other preposition with "Welcome aboard".  This is because you are  *[aboard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aboard)* the vessel, not "aboard on" the vessel.  "Aboard" basically already means "on", so there's no reason for any other preposition.

Is it possible you're confusing "aboard" with "[on board](http://grammarist.com/usage/onboard-on-board/)", which is another phrase that means pretty much the same thing?  You wouldn't use another preposition after "on board" either, though.

Comment: So, if I used "Welcome aboard the xyz train", would that be right?

Comment: @lekonchekon - Yes, that's right.